# net::ERR_FAILED for network item in manifest.cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cache-manifest, manifest.cache

My cache manifest file looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

calendar.html
scripts/jquery.js
scripts/calendar.js

NETWORK:

https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
```

My calendar.html looks something like:

```
<html manifest="calendar.cache">
  <head>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: inline">
      <span>Authorize access to Google Calendar API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        console.log("ready");
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I disable the cache everything works fine. However, when the cache is enabled I get an error for the `apis.google.com/js/client.js` file. The error is `jquery.js:5 GET https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth&_=1474962265124 net::ERR_FAILED`. This is for google chrome browser, but I get a similar error for firefox. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused due to those parameters which you are passing for client.js ie.`?onload=checkAuth`

In web whenever you pass any parameter that request is considered unique.So as far as the browser is concerned scripts declared in your manifest aren't the same

```
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js // script A
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth //script B ≠ script A
```

But in `calendar.cache` you have declared only script A as non-cached.So now you can guess changing manifest to below would solve the issue

```
CACHE MANIFEST
calendar.html
scripts/jquery.js
scripts/calendar.js

NETWORK:
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth
```

Ofc just removing `onload=checkAuth` could also work in-case you don't need the callback.Just wipe entire cache and reload to see the magic!